# Tablesorter: sorting numbers vs formatted numbers

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

Suppose I received data from an AJAX call and place them in a php-generated list like so:

```
    echo"
            <div class='mainContainer'>
                <table id='aNumberList' class='standardSort'>
                    <thead>
                        <tr class='colSort'>
                            <th class='c1FL'>ID</th>
                            <th class='c2FL'>Amount</th>            
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                    ";
                      foreach ($lines as $line)
                      {
                            echo "<td class='c1FL'>".$line['id']."</td>";
                         //   echo "<td class='c2FL'>".number_format ($line['total'], 2, '.', ' ')."</td>"; 
                            echo "<td class='c2FL'>".$line['total']."</td>";
                      }
                    echo "
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>             
            <script> $('#aNumberList').tablesorter({ widgets: ['zebra'], widgetOptions : { zebra : ['normal-row', 'alt-row']}}); </script>…
```

One can see from the commented-out line that I can:

a) either leave all `$line['total']` unformatted and be able to sort them as numbers;

b) or format all `$line['total']` and be unable to sort them as a numbers (for `number_format` will return strings).

I wish to both format numbers *and* be able to use tablesorter to sort them, bearing in mind that tablesorter is my standing option.

**Is there a way out of the coding dilemma?**

Comment: If you're using a plugin you should add a link to the documentation. There are hundreds of "tablesorter" plugins out there. From the options it looks like [this](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) plugin. If so, then check the options [`usNumberFormat`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#usnumberformat), [`textExtraction`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#textextraction) and [`textAttribute`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#textattribute)

Comment: This tablesorter actually is the one I am referring to. Checked the options. Thank you.